# Adjacency matrix and connectivity proof

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be graph on $n$ vertices, $A$ its adjacency matrix, and $I_{n}$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix. Prove that $G$ is connected iff the matrix $(I_{n} + A)^{n-1}$ has no 0s.

My proof:

*If the graph is connected the matrix $(I_{n} + A)^{n-1}$ has no 0s.*

The identity matrix  takes care of the non-zero values for the diagonal (otherwise the diagonals would be 0 since self-loops are disallowed in simple graphs).
If the graph is connected there must exist a path between any two vertices $u,v \in G$. $A^{n-1}_{i,j}$ represents the number of paths of length $n-1$ between any two vertices. If any $A^{n-1}_{i,j}$ would be 0, that would mean that there would not be any path connecting those vertices. Thus, the graph would be disconnected. But we assumed that it was connected

*If the matrix $(I_{n} + A)^{n-1}$ has no 0s then G is connected*

If every $(I_{n} + A)^{n-1}$ is non-zero this means that there exists at least one path of length $n - 1$ between any two vertices. If this is the case, the graph must be connected.

Is this correct?

Comment: "If any $A^{n-1}_{i,j}$ would be 0, that would mean that there would not be any path connecting those vertices". No, that would mean that there aren't paths of length $n-1$ connecting the vertices. If it happens to be equivalent, than it certainly is necessary to prove this. I think the other direction is fine.

Comment: Thank you, I now see my mistake in the first part. I will try to amend it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to check whether the $i,j$ entry of $A^{n-1}$ is equal to $1$; not every connected graph has a path of length $n-1$ between *every* two vertices.  Also, you're wrong about what it means for every entry of $(I+A)^{n-1}$ to be non-zero.

**Hint:** use the binomial expansion
$$
(I+A)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}k A^k 
$$

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Would you mind to elaborate a little bit more? I did the binomial expansion and got $\binom{n-1}{0}A^{0}+\binom{n-1}{1}A^{1}+.....+\binom{n-1}{n-1}A^{n-1}$ which is a linear combination of all the As. but I still don't know how this helps.

Comment: The idea is that $[(I + A)^{n-1}]_{i,j}$ is non-zero if and only if $[A^k]_{i,j}$ is non-zero for some $k$ from $0$ to $n-1$.